# Show that in space $\mathbb R^3 $ the vectors $x=(1,1,0), y=(0,1,2) $ and $z=(3,1,-4)$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am having a hard time in proving this.

It would be a great help.

Can someone help me with this?

***without the matrix form

Comment: Set it up in matrix form and apply the gauss-jordan method.

Comment: @Curl Presumably, that's what "without the matrix form" wants you not to do.

Comment: Why are you having a hard time with this? If you know what linear independence means, that should tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, Even I see. There is a solution in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Solve the System $$\alpha[1,1,0]+\beta[0,1,2]+\gamma[3,1,-4]=[0,0,0]$$

Comment: Now, solve it in one line. :)

Comment: checked this method already. it shows that these vectors are linearly dependent

Comment: @InduHarsha What values do you get for $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: @InduHarsha Then that's probably because the vectors are indeed linearly dependenet

Answer (score 3):

They're not linearly independent:  $z=3x-2y$

Comment: perhaps you are having a hard time showing that they are linearly independent because they are not

Answer (score 0):

If they are linearly independent, their scalar product should be non-zero.

$$[\vec a,\vec b, \vec c] = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\  3 & 1 & -4 \end{vmatrix} = 0. $$
 So the given vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: You mean dependant

Comment: That determinant is $0$. Also, no matrix form is allowed

Comment: $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\  3 & 1 & -4 \end{vmatrix} = 1\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & -4 \end{vmatrix}-1\begin{vmatrix}0 & 2\\3 & -4 \end{vmatrix} = -6+6=0. $

Comment: @J. W. Tanner  Sorry, yes you are right they are LD, I have edited it now.

Comment: @ jilandercy yes you are right.